# Where should I look for code that validates forms upon input from the user?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, validation

I've been googling phrases like "form validation javascript" and "form validation ajax" but I only find code involving form validation upon the form submission. I want to write code that determines whether the field has valid input right when the user is inputting the data. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), which does both.